Constant expression contains invalid operations(I use dirname)
The following statement will show error "Constant expression contains invalid operations", why?
const DEBUG_FILE = dirname(__FILE__) . '/debug.txt';


Because dirname() is a function. That's not allowed because it cannot be evaluated during compilation. Yes, PHP does some form of compilation before it executes the script. Constants are reduced to their basic value during this compilation step. Functions however require real execution, and that cannot be done during compilation.

Use __DIR__ instead of dirname(__FILE__).
